# Named regex capturing groups with special characters

Tags: php, regex, symfony

Im working on Symfony project where we have the special need of dot separated route parameter names. Sounds like a pretty easy task but im probably just way to stupid.

After searching my way through the symfony router component I found the regex that matches parameters in routes:

```
// Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler::compilePattern
preg_match_all('#\{\w+\}#', $pattern, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Well changing that should do the trick not? So I changed the regex to also match dots:

```
#\{[\w\.]+\}#
```

But now im getting the following error: `preg_match(): Compilation failed: syntax error in subpattern name (missing terminator) at offset 17`

So let's take a look at the generated cache file:

```
if (preg_match("#^/movie/(?P<movie.year>[^/]++)/(?P<movie.title>[^/]++)/?$#s", $pathinfo, $matches)) {
```

My first guess was that I probably have to escape the dott.

So inside `Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\Dumper\PhpMatcherDumper` I've added a little preg_replace to escape that dott. The escaping works the regex not. Same error.

### TL;DR

This brings me to my main Question:

> Can named capturing groups contain special characters like a dott?

*PS: I know, I should never directly modify symfony core files and avoid overwriting core components. :)*

Any suggestions for other solutions? My next idea would be to overwrite the routing component which I would like to avoid..

Comment: You cannot have DOT in the name of capturing groups.

Comment: @anubhava Thats was also my conclusion, but why?

Comment: That is as per PCRE specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @anubhava pointed out this is simply not possible, to get around this problem I just replace the `.` dots with an horrible stupid string. I don't like this solution but it works.